# Como puedo cambiar de color una fila con jquery según valor en td?

Tags: jquery

Tengo este código para generar una tabla dinámicamente con jquery, los valores son tomados de un json, pero no puedo cambiar el color de la fila segun el valor que haya en la columna "Respuesta Banco". Estuve intentado de esta forma y no me da resultado, solo puedo mostrar la consulta pero no cambiar colores

```
                    $(document).ready(function(){


                    var url="Historial.php";
                    $("#tablajson tbody").html("");
                    $.getJSON(url,function(historial){
                    $.each(historial, function(i,movimiento){
                    var newRow =
                    "<tr>"
                    +"<td>"+movimiento.FechaHora+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+movimiento.RespuestaCompletaBanco+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+movimiento.CreditCard+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+movimiento.MontoTransaccion+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+movimiento.EmpleadoId+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+movimiento.Nombre+"</td>"
                    +"</tr>";
                    $(newRow).appendTo("#tablajson tbody");
                    })
                    });

                   $('#tablajson td:last-child:contains(NOT)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
                   $('#tablajson td:last-child:contains(ERROR)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
                   $('#tablajson td:last-child:contains(CAPTURED)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
                    });
```

Comment: Por qué utilizas `td:last-child`? Veo que la última columna de la tabla es el nombre del movimiento no la respuesta del banco.

Comment: Debería usar otro selector. He intentado con td:nth-child(2), y tampoco no se si funcione como arreglo, que inicia con indice en 0, Igual intenté cambiando de posición la Columna Respuesta Banco para que se justifique usar td:last-child y nada

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver, te agradezco mucho tu tiempo, tu respuesta fue de mucha ayuda ya que cambiando last-child por nth-child(2) pude resolverlo, mi principal error era también que estaban mal colocadas mis opciones de colores